# Avoid modal dismiss on submit form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a form to allow users to change their passwords by using a form inside a modal from bootstrap. So it is possible to show an alert if anything goes wrong, but the modal always closes after the send button is pressed or by pressing the Enter key (as shown in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400149/avoid-modal-dismiss-on-enter-keypress). Opening again the modal it shows the alerts, so I think I have to find the way to don't dismiss the modal after submit the form. I tried to re-write the div container after submit the form but it doesn't works. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: The approach would be to close or show the error based on the response from an ajax submission. You'll need to show code if you're expecting a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finnally do it in the ajax way.