# Bootstrap 3 modal is closed when enter is pressed, but form is not submitted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal, with a form inside of the modal:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Add new page</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal add-new-page-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Label -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="labelInput">Label</label>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                      <input id="labelInput" name="labelInput" type="text" data-field="label" class="form-control input-md">
                      <span class="help-block">Page label</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button (Double) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="closeBtn"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button id="closeBtn" name="closeBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" id="saveBtn" name="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary add-page" value="Add">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to catch the `submit` event via jQuery:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    alert("foo");
    return false;
});
```

The form is not submitted via pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (when an text input is focused), but it is submitted when <kbd>Add</kbd> button (that is a `submit` one) is clicked.

I cannot find why the form is not submitted via Enter. The modal simply closes, but `submit` event is not emitted/fired.

[**JSFDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yAzrs/) - where the issue can be reproduced

Tested on Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972) and Firefox 31.0. Same issue on both browsers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can simply change the order from

```
close-button

submit-button
```

to

```
submit-button

close-button
```

or add

```
 type="button"
```

to your close button so it doesn´t get interpreted as submit button

cheers

Comment: I changed the order of the buttons and **it works**. But whyyyy?! I want to use built-in browser submit settings, so other scripts are useless.

Comment: well there seems to be some bootstrap.js that overrides the default behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400149/avoid-modal-dismiss-on-enter-keypress

Comment: I saw that question, but they don't explain this problem. :-)

Comment: well the correct answer would be to add type="button" to your close button, then you dont have to change the order

Comment: Add this info to your answer and a JSFIDDLE as well. That's the best. In the previous question, they were setting `type="button"` for the `x` icon. Thank you so much.

Comment: this has been haunting me for months but i always tabled the issue. THANK YOU for the `type="button"` solution!

Comment: adding type="button" for close button was worked for me +1

Comment: cheers. For bootstrap 4, adding type="button" on the cancel button works for me !!!

Comment: this is lifesafer. spend hours to figure it out lel

Answer (score 3):

I've added a handler to the modal close event to submit the form before closing the modal, like so:

```
$("#myModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
    $(this).find('form').submit(); 
});
```

I've updated the jsfiddle correspondingly, http://jsfiddle.net/yAzrs/2/

You could also listen for the enter key within the form itself, something like this:

```
$('form').on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) $(this).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

jQuery doesn't know you've pressed enter just simply by you pressing enter. Include the jQuery above but with your own code inside the if statement and hopefully it should work

Comment: I know that, but I want to catch `submit` event.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter in the input field caused button with data-dismiss="modal" to be fired
just change data-dismiss="modal" to your submit button and remove from your close button

```
<input type="submit" id="saveBtn" name="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary add-page" data-dismiss="modal" value="Add">
```